# Can I upload songs to Itunes from second HD?

Tags: itunes, windows, ssd

I have 2 Hdd's one solid state and the other is moving parts. I have Itunes on my solid state and all of my music on the secondary. Is it possible to to have iTunes play music from that drive without me having to waste all of my ssd with mp3's? Windows Media Player can do it with no problem so I'm sure iTunes can. Anyone understand what I'm asking for or have a solution?

If it matters I'm using Windows 7 Pro and Itunes 11.4

Comment: Check this Apple doc about moving iTunes Library: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1364?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open iTunes. Choose Edit > Preferences. Click the Advanced tab in the Preferences window. Select the "Keep iTunes Media folder organized" checkbox. Open iTunes. From the Edit menu, choose Preferences. Click the Advanced tab in the Preferences window. Click the Change button in the iTunes Media folder location pane. In the Change Media Folder Location window that appears, navigate to the location where you would like your new Media folder to be created. Then click&drag or copy and paste music files to the folder "Automatically add to iTunes" and it will automatically populate iTunes.